# How many recessed lighting do I need for my living room?

Tags: electrical, lighting, recessed-lighting

Living room size: 18 L x 16.5 W x 8 H

Using 6" cans with BR40 flood lights
around 60watt equivalent LEDs, so about 800 lumens

Based on this, it looks like I should be getting 9 lights? Assuming cans are at least 3 feet away from walls and corners, and 3 cans in each row and column evenly spaced apart.

9 holes in my living room seems like a lot. Do you think I can get away with 5, using 1 on each corner and 1 right in the middle? Make like a "X" formation. Or is that not enough in terms of lighting up the living room?

Comment: That’s a lot of bright light.  I suppose tastes vary, but I wouldn’t want that in my living room.  If your set on recessed lighting you might consider doing a few wall wash recessed lights a few feet out from the wall that light the wall, reflecting light from the wall lights the room.

Comment: I have an 18x18 spare room with 4 BR30’s in the ceiling, it’s more than enough.

Comment: How do you plan to light the ceiling?  Recessed lights create shadows around themselves.

Comment: Yes a lot of bright lights but will be controlled with a dimmer. Is your 4 BR30 3 deer away from wall? Or more?

Comment: I’m not sure if I’ll have an issue looking at the shadows. I’ll have to build it first and see if it bugs me. Maybe I’ll do 4 in each corner, 3 feet away and see how that goes